# Ошибка. Значение не может быть определенным DataSet

Tags: c#

Имеется dataGridView в нем заполнены данные (имеются также другие таблицы которые привязаны по Primary Key)
при сохранении вылетает ошибка. База данных SQL Server'a

и есть ещё предупреждении:

```
Warning 1 Field 'abc.Form1.ds' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null
```

Код:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
        {
            connection.Open();
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
            commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
            adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("sp_CreateUser", connection);
            adapter.InsertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@тип ппп", SqlDbType.Text, 50, "тип ппп"));
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@тип ффф", SqlDbType.Text, 0, "тип ффф"));
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@тип ззз", SqlDbType.Text, 50, "тип ззз"));
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@тип ммм", SqlDbType.Text, 0, "тип ммм"));
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@тип ккк", SqlDbType.Text, 50, "тип ккк"));
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@тип щщщ", SqlDbType.Text, 0, "тип щщщ"));

            SqlParameter parameter = adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@№ азс", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "№ азс");
            parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            adapter.Update(ds);
```

Код в шапке:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataSet ds;
      ...
 string sql = "SELECT * FROM [Азс1]";
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас в коде есть место где вы записываете в поле ds значение? Типа `ds = new DataSet();`?

Comment: Ну вот по умолчанию там и лежит null, а это недопустимый аргумент для Update

Comment: Судя по другому вашему вопросу, вы используете `DataGridView`. Покажите код, как данные попадают в этот грид. Ведь из датасета? Вот этот же самый датасет и нужно использовать.

Comment: Ну вы поле `ds` объявить то объявили, но ничего в него не записали, от того и ошибка.

Comment: @tym32167 помогите исправить

Comment: @tym32167 нет..

Comment: вы задали этот вопрос уже 3-й раз. не стоит так делать. если вы хотите уточнить или исправить свой вопрос - просто отредактируйте оригинал, а не плодите копии

Comment: Сейчас у вас падает т.к. вы в  adapter.Update передаете переменную, которую вы нигде не инициализируете. Вы должны заполнять этот ds где-то при выборке данных.

Answer (score 0):

Вот в эту переменную

```
DataSet ds;
```

Вы не инициализировали, поэтому когда обновляете адаптер

```
adapter.Update(ds);
```

и будет ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Была похожая история, инициализировал вот так

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet("Таблица");
```

и всё заработало.