# Почему не сохраняет в базу данных данные

Tags: c#

Почему не сохраняет в базу данных (SQL Server) данные из dataGridView?
Код без ошибок.

Код:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
        {
            connection.Open();
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
            commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
            adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("sp_CreateUser", connection);
            adapter.InsertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@тип ппп", SqlDbType.Text, 50, "тип ппп"));
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@тип ффф", SqlDbType.Text, 0, "тип ффф"));
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@тип ззз", SqlDbType.Text, 50, "тип ззз"));
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@тип ммм", SqlDbType.Text, 0, "тип ммм"));
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@тип ккк", SqlDbType.Text, 50, "тип ккк"));
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@тип щщщ", SqlDbType.Text, 0, "тип щщщ"));

            SqlParameter parameter = adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@№ азс", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "№ азс");
            parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
}
```

Comment: Чтобы сохранило, нужно вызвать `adapter.Update`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка. Значение не может быть определенным DataSet](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/833658/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%97%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-dataset)

Answer (score 2):

После `using(){ ... }` соединение закрыто и непригодно к использованию.

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnStr)
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
```

Адаптер сам откроет и закроет соединение.

Comment: спасибо! вам, что помогаете